# Would this .htaccess alone cause 404 and 500 errors?

Tags: htaccess, 404, cpanel, http-code-500

My site is down and depending on what I change I get a 500 error or a 404 or a "Forbidden you are not authorized" error. In checking my .htaccess files I found a strange one:

```
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
  Require all denied
</IfModule>
```

Would "Deny from all" and "Require all denied" be the reason my site is down? It seems like this would be the cause, right?

Comment: Have you tried removing it all and seeing if your site works?

Comment: As well, I usually reserve these types of statements for the configuration files and not .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

> I get a 500 error or a 404 or a "**Forbidden you are not authorized**" error.

The code you posted should result in a 403 Forbidden for all visitors. The first `<IfModule>` block applies to Apache 2.2 (and below) and the second block applies to Apache 2.4+ (strictly Apache 2.3+). Although the first block alone would "work" on both Apache 2.2 and 2.4 if you removed the `<IfModule>` wrapper.

I say "should", because, whatever error document is being served when the 403 is triggered could change the HTTP status to something else. Sometimes a 404 might be preferable to a 403 and sometimes the server is simply misconfigured.

You also shouldn't be getting different errors with the same block of code.

> Would "Deny from all" and "Require all denied" be the reason my site is down?

If that is the only code in your `.htaccess` file then yes, that would certainly be one big reason! However, that code is quite deliberate and looks a bit dubious since it is specifically targeting multiple server versions.

> ...depending on what I change

What things were you changing?